# Get queueName in Message listner of RabbitMq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, websocket, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am creating multiple consumers in the loop by which I am able to listen to multiple queues. The issue in this approach is I am able to get the events from the different queues but all the queues are using the same consumer so it is hard to recognize for which queue this event happens. It will be good if I will get the queue name under the consumer section.

```
          consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                };
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ea` variable has some interesting fields, have you check that?

`ea.Exchange` shows this message has published from which exchange.

`ea.RoutingKey` shows the route info of the message. probably have the queue name in it.

Also, you can put your headers in the message when your are defining them.

```
IBasicProperties props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
props.Headers.Add("queueName",  "myQueue1");
channel.BasicPublish(exchangeName,
                   routingKey, props,
                   messageBodyBytes);
```

and in the consumer function you can read them :

```
consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var name = ea.BasicProperties.Headers["queueName"];
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I can't add queue name in the header because we are sending the data through an exchange which is bound with many queues. So It will be difficult to add different headers in the queue.

Comment: probably you should add more details to your question, cause I can not understand what you are trying to do. If you are creating a standard or normal app, probably your topology is wrong, else you should eat your frog and do the difficult thing.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is using "consumerTag" in channel.BasicConsume

```
channel.BasicConsume(..., consumerTag: "YourQueueName");
```

And then you can retrieve the queue name in message listner:

```
consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                var queueName = ea.ConsumerTag;
            };
```

Warning: In the case that ConsumerTag is important to your system, do not use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no queue field on the message headers or fields, based on my re-search of message object.
The only fields related to queue name are from dead-lettered messages, which save in the headers object of properties the `x-first-death-queue`.